# PHP files are downloaded instead of getting interpreted

Tags: debian, php, apache-http-server, php.ini, php5

I'm encountring some difficulties with my Apache2/PHP5. All was well-configured and working, but after reinstalling `apache2`, the PHP files are displayed without being interpreted.

I tried many workarounds like:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

in the `httpd.conf` file, but still get the same issue. Please note that `httpd.conf` was not changed.

Answer (score 4):

Are you loading PHP Module ?
In your httpd.conf, check :

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Of course, you must change module path, to where your libphp5.so is.

Furthermore, you also need your entry

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

If you want to use indexes with .php, modify the dir_module condition :

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

But before running all of that, you could run an apt-get :

```
 apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: The last line is the important one. The package installer should have done all the detail work for you. If it didn't, try re-installing the package before manipulating the Apache configuration directly.