# Recommended way of installing PHP 5.4

Tags: linux, debian, php, debian-wheezy

**PHP 5.4** is stable for quite some time now. However, when I type

```
apt-get install php5
```

PHP 5.3 gets installed.

**Question:** Why? And what is the preferred way of installing PHP 5.4? Should I choose a different package or should I change the sources? If so, what exactly is the name of the other package or source?

**Background information**

The server is running Debian Wheezy x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian Wheezy ships with PHP 5.4.4 as can be seen on [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/php5). Are you sure that you have Debian 7.0 Wheezy installed? You can test that by running the `lsb_release -a` command.

Look at `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` too. Do not forget to run `apt-get update` prior to `apt-get install`.

Comment: That's very weird. I downloaded and installed this image: http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.0.0/amd64/iso-cd/debian-7.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso but `lsb_release -a` shows that Debian 6.0.6 is installed. How could this happen?

Comment: @DevilsChild Are you sure about that? Could it be that you used an older image instead of the downloaded one? It seems unlikely to me that the Debian installer has such a severe issue.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. It rather seems like I messed something up here. With Wheezy installed, PHP 5.4 works. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One way to get PHP latest stable 5.4 on Debian is to install it through [the dotdeb repositories](http://www.dotdeb.org/). Add to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
```

Install their key:

```
wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
cat dotdeb.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Finally run `apt-get update`. You now get the latest PHP version, including all the extras. Do note that PHP 5.4 does not contain Suhosin – I ran into that problem myself and was wondering why `apt-get` wouldn't update it.

The benefit of using the dotdeb repos is that they also work on Squeeze (just use `squeeze` in the `sources.list`).

Comment: I did this (because I can't upgrade to Wheezy right now) and now, everytime I call a page on my web site, I retrieve a file called "download" with the PHP source code. What should I do?

Comment: Looks like PHP isn't properly configured or not loaded as a module. See: [PHP files are downloaded instead of getting interpreted](http://superuser.com/questions/392301/php-files-are-downloaded-instead-of-getting-interpreted) – if that doesn't help I would suggest you ask this as a new question though and include the details about your OS, what you did, and possibly include the output you got from installing the packages, and your httpd.conf file.