# Apache downloads php files instead of running their source

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, php

I have just recently upgraded PHP 5.3 to **5.4** on my Debian Squeeze server. Now, instead of executing PHP files, Apache just downloads them, which is *really* bad.

When I try to follow [these](https://superuser.com/questions/392301/php-files-are-downloaded-instead-of-getting-interpreted) steps, I get "broken packages" upon installing the `libapache2-mod-php5` package.

Also the answer tells me to add something to my httpd.conf, but it's empty.

**Question:** How can I make apache execute php files again, instead of just passing them through as download?

`dpkg -l | grep php` returns this

```
rc  libapache2-mod-php5                 5.3.3-7+squeeze15            server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)
rc  php5-cli                            5.3.3-7+squeeze15            command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
ii  php5-common                         5.4.15-1~dotdeb.2            Common files for packages built from the php5 source
rc  php5-gd                             5.3.3-7+squeeze15            GD module for php5
rc  php5-mcrypt                         5.3.3-7+squeeze15            MCrypt module for php5
rc  php5-mysql                          5.3.3-7+squeeze15            MySQL module for php5
rc  php5-suhosin                        0.9.32.1-1                   advanced protection module for php5
rc  phpmyadmin                          4:3.3.7-7                    MySQL web administration tool
```

**And `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` produces this error**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Depends: libdb5.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libxml2 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.7.8.dfsg-2+squeeze7 is to be installed
                       Recommends: php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `dpkg -l | grep php` just for completeness? `apache2.conf` is the file you need when `httpd.conf` is empty. But I'm sure you need `libapache2-mod-php5` – so what are the "broken packages" exactly? Can you show the full apt output?

Comment: Sure. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the message means is that `libapache2-mod-php5` is not installed (`rc` means removed (1st letter, r), but configuration files not removed (2nd letter c)). So in order to make apache execute php files again, you will need to reinstall it.

Your package manager says you have unmet dependencies. Basically, as smart as it is, it couldn't figure a way to do what you asked it to do (probably during an update), so you'll need to figure it yourself. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) for a detailed procedure. The question is specifically on Ubuntu, but most of it is applicable to Debian as well.

In short, you'll need to figure out why those packages are not installable. Use `apt-get install libdb5.1` to figure out why `libdb5.1` cannot be installed, then  `apt-get install libssl1.0.0`, and finally  `apt-get install libxml2`. This will in turn point you to some other packages that are missing or with a wrong version. Once you figure out where is the problem, you'll probably need to `apt-get install -f` that package (`-f` means force).